# Scroll to element on the page without jquery (Vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm aware there are many similar questions, but! They all seem to be from 2010 - 2013 and require the use of jQuery which I want to avoid.

Is there an easy way using Javascript to scroll to an element with a certain id and control where it lands?

I have tried to use `scrollIntoView()` but I was unable to get it to land where I wanted it. Even with the extra configuration detailed [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) Is there a more precise way of doing it??

I have tried

```
document.getElementById('6QWsZnqyuAKke20CgG4WIQ')
  .scrollIntoView({'every different config option'});
```

Usually what happens is it would scroll to far or not enough, never exactly where I want it. I have also checked the browser compatibility and the `options` are not available in certain browsers. Is there a more precise way of doing it??

Thanks

Comment: Show the code you tried, and expand on _"couldn't get it to land where I wanted"_, does that mean it went to far, didn't go far enough, didn't do anything?

Comment: I haven't tried, but potentially you can get the distance from the top for the element that you want to scroll to, using scrollTop, and then pass it to  window.scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
el = document.getElementById('your-el-id');
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
window.scrollTo(rect.x, rect.y)
```

This code will position the element on top of the window. Simply modify the values in `window.scrollTo()` to get the desired position.

Comment: Im getting a linting error x and y does not exist on rect, are they meant  to be numbers?

Comment: I am unsure why you would receive a linting error. Calling `.x` and `.y` will return the number for the x and y coordinates of the element's top left corner. What IDE are you using?

Comment: Im writing this in an angular application so its a tslint error sorry that says `[ts] Property 'x' does not exist on type ClientRec | DOMRect` I will figure out how to fix it

Comment: Ah, Typescript. That is why. The code is valid javascript and will get the job done. I believe making this proper Typescript is outside the scope of this question.